# ¿Cómo añadir tags a la imagen subida a imgur api desde python?

Tags: python

Estoy programando un bot para que pueda subir las imagenes a imgur de forma local a mi cuenta de imgur pero tengo un problema y esque necesito añadir los tags de cada imagen desde python

Este es mi código completo que estoy usando actualmente:

```
import requests
import base64

headers1 = {'Authorization': 'Bearer Xxxx',}
params = {
        'title':f'uwu', 
        'description':'hola',
        'name':'Hey',
        'add_tags':'Fortnite',

        'image': base64.b64encode(open('cosmetico.png', 'rb').read())}
r = requests.post(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', headers=headers1, data=params)
data = r.json()["data"]["link"]
id = r.json()["data"]["id"]
```

He intentado añadir add_tags o tags pero ninguno funciona

Me gustaria poder añadir los tags:

[image]

Pero no encuentro la manera de poder hacerlo

¿Me podrian ayudar? muchas gracias antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo he leído bien, los tags pertenecen a una gallería y se deben agregar antes:

[https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/tags/{{galleryHash}}](https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/tags/%7B%7BgalleryHash%7D%7D)
Update the tags for a post in the gallery

HEADERS
Authorization
Bearer {{accessToken}}
BODYformdata
id
{{galleryHash}}
Required. ID of the gallery item

tags
funny,cats
Required. The name of the tags you wish to associate with a post. Can be passed as tags[]=funny&tags[]=cat or tags=funny,cat

de esta fuente: https://apidocs.imgur.com/#performance-tips

```
import http.client
import mimetypes
from codecs import encode

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.imgur.com")
dataList = []
boundary = 'wL36Yn8afVp8Ag7AmP8qZ0SA4n1v9T'
dataList.append(encode('--' + boundary))
dataList.append(encode('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=id;'))

dataList.append(encode('Content-Type: {}'.format('text/plain')))
dataList.append(encode(''))

dataList.append(encode("{{galleryHash}}"))
dataList.append(encode('--' + boundary))
dataList.append(encode('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=tags;'))

dataList.append(encode('Content-Type: {}'.format('text/plain')))
dataList.append(encode(''))

dataList.append(encode("funny,cats"))
dataList.append(encode('--'+boundary+'--'))
dataList.append(encode(''))
body = b'\r\n'.join(dataList)
payload = body
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer {{accessToken}}',
  'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary={}'.format(boundary)
}
conn.request("POST", "/3/gallery/tags/{{galleryHash}}", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Entiendo que una vez creada la galería todas las imágenes tendrán esas etiquetas, porque en el Post de la imagen con el api, según documentación no puedes agregar un tag al subir la imagen.